# Using S3Image from aws-amplify-react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, amazon-s3, expo, aws-amplify

I am using React Native / Expo to build an app. I have AWS S3 set up, as well as cognito with user sign in using `withAuthenticator`. I have got image uploading working fine, but when I try to display the images it just does not work. Here is the code I am using:

```
const ImageList = ({ 
  imageId,
  getImages,
  images = [],
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getImages(imageId);
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Card title="Images">
        {images.map((value, idx) => (
          <S3Image imgKey={value.key} level="private" />
        ))}
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
}
```

My `getImages` function ( redux action ) using `Storage.list` to get a list of images in the S3 bucket. It returns the values fine. But the `S3Images` component isn't rendering anything. I have also tried just getting the URL from S3 using `Storage.get`, and then using `Image` from react-native, but that also is not working. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add width and height in a style prop to the S3Image component. If either width or height are 0, the component does not show.

```
<S3Image imgKey={value.key} level="private" style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}/>
```